# rewrite java code to groovy code

Tags: java, groovy

I have this code in Java.

```
MyObject a = MyObject.newMyObject();
a.setParameter(Parameters.BASIC);
CompositeObject co = CompositeObject.newCompositeObject();
co.add(BasicFactory.newInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), ResourceType.BASIC, a);
```

Is it possible to do it better using `Groovy`?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Using closures, some instantiations inside `{`, not using setters and etc.

Comment: drop the `;`.  use `with`.

Comment: But what to do with `factories`? Leave it as is? I hoped It's possible to do something with them in `groovy`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start.

```
def a = MyObject.newMyObject()
a.parameter = Parameters.BASIC
def co = CompositeObject.newCompositeObject()
co.add(BasicFactory.newInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), ResourceType.BASIC, a))
```

If all you really need is the `co` then you can do something like this to limit the scope of temporary variables.

```
def co = CompositeObject.newCompositeObject().with {
    def a = MyObject.newMyObject()
    a.parameter = Parameters.BASIC    
    def factory = BasicFactory.newInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), ResourceType.BASIC, a)
    co.add factory

    return it
}
```